# Unable to receive body of a post request in RestSharp 107.1.2

Tags: c#, restsharp

I've just updated my RestSharp application to 107.1.2 and are now unable to send post request.
To test the problem I've set up a small express.js webserver to receive the requests from my C# application. On every post request I made, there is always no body available.

```
RestClientOptions options = new RestClientOptions("http://127.0.0.1:3000");
RestClient client = new RestClient(options);
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("api/test");
request.AddParameter("test1", "test1");
request.AddParameter("test2", "test2");
request.AddParameter("test3", "test3");
TestResponse response = await client.PostAsync<TestResponse>(request);
```

The code is based on the QueryString documentation https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#query-string. And yes, the params from the request I receive on the webserver are also empty. To test plain post request, I even tried the following:

```
RestClientOptions options = new RestClientOptions("http://127.0.0.1:3000");
RestClient client = new RestClient(options);
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("api/test");

const string json = "{ data: { foo: \"bar\" } }";
request.AddStringBody(json, ContentType.Json);
TestResponse response = await client.PostAsync<TestResponse>(request);
```

I can't find the problem why the requests are sent without an actual post body. In the previous version I've updated from, everything works fine.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please Try this :

`request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;`

`request.AddJsonBody(new { A = "foo", B = "bar" });`

or

```
const string json = "{ data: { foo: \"bar\" } }";
request.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Comment: Thank your for your response. request.AddJsonBody still results in an empty body on request. Content is not a valid member of RestRequest so both options have unfortunately not led to success.

Answer (score 0):

```
RestClientOptions options = new RestClientOptions("http://127.0.0.1:3000");
var client = new RestSharp.RestClient(options);
var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest(RestSharp.Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json;
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
const string json = "{ data: { foo: \"bar\" } }";
request.AddBody(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json));
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Thank you. Doesn't work either. Also think you're code is based on a wrong version of RestSharp. As I've mentioned I'm using the latest 107.1.2. Sync Methods like Execute have been removed in recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please

```
       RestClientOptions options = new RestClientOptions("http://127.0.0.1:3000");
       var restClient = new RestClient(options);

        var restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST)
        {
            RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
        };

        const string json = "{ data: { foo: \"bar\" } }";
        request.AddBody(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json));

        var result = restClient.Post<TResponse>(restRequest);

        if (!result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            throw new HttpException($"Item not found: {result.ErrorMessage}");
        }

        return result.Data;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble understanding why do you think the request is made without the body. I would expect that the express API gives you no body, but it doesn't mean the request has no body.

I traced your requests, and you can see them [here](https://requestbin.com/r/en49p2y04wqqr/24TiFSYAcZF0ktodndHemoltrTt).

The first snippet produces the following request:
[image]

As you can see it has the correct content type and the body is correctly formed as form URL encoded body content.

Your second snippet also produces the correct request with JSON body:

[image]

It is impossible to say why your server doesn't understand these requests, as you haven't specified what the server needs, but I don't see any issues with those requests per se.

Answer (score 0):

If you you want to add parameters in the request use below way:

```
RestClient client = new("http://127.0.0.1:3000");
RestRequest restRequest = new("api/test");
restRequest.AddParameter("test1", "test1");
request.AddParameter("test2", "test2");
request.AddParameter("test3", "test3");
RestResponse response = client.ExecuteAsync(restRequest,Method.Post).Result;      
Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
```

If you you want to add json body in the request use the below way:

```
RestClient client = new("http://127.0.0.1:3000");
RestRequest restRequest = new("api/test");
string requestBody=  "{\"data\":{\"foo\":\"bar\"}}"
restRequest.AddStringBody(requestBody, DataFormat.Json);
RestResponse response = client.ExecuteAsync(restRequest, Method.Post).Result;
Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
```